# Imaging - how can I make a terminal prompt on first boot

Tags: scripts, administration, oem

I image many computers with Ubuntu. I use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and have a script that does things like setting the hostname on first boot. I'd like this script to ask me a question. How can this be achieved? Upstart is concurrent and doesn't show any particular terminal so I'm not sure how this could be done.

If you're wondering why, I'd like for it to ask me what school I'm at which would run a specific script for that school's customizations. This way I can have one company image that runs everywhere I work in.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Clonezilla but looking at the boot parameters [here](http://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=clonezilla-live/doc/99_Misc/00_live-initramfs-manual.doc#00_live-initramfs-manual.doc) I would say you just need to make sure that ocs_live_batch="no" so that your script is interactive and then you should be able to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-in-a-linux-shell-script) in to read input from the terminal.